# Android: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION Permission Sources

Tags: android, permissions, geolocation

In my app I only request ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission. Will it work with only wifi access? For example, on a tablet that has no cell connection? I have no way to test this since this permission alone won't work the emulator because the emulator requires GPS_PROVIDER permission.

Comment: Yes, it will work on either of the following: bluetooth, wifi and cellular connection. Even if cell connection is not there, it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION will only work with Wifi, Cellular and Bluetooth networks. It'll not get you location from GPS

Ref . https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location